# Issue intstalling Entity Framework on VS Code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am doing a small project on VS code. I need to install Entity Framework. When I use the command

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -v 3.1.2
```

I get the response

> info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' into project 'C:\Users\111\datingapp\datingapp.api\datingapp.api.csproj'.
>   info : Restoring packages for C:\Users\111\datingapp\datingapp.api\datingapp.api.csproj...
>
> **Error**: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
>   **Error**: no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I have never had any issues with the nuget package manager until now. I have done any extensive search and can not seem to find this answer. Please help.

Comment: did you check if your .csproj file has entity framework listed there ? If so, what do you get when you try to run dotnet restore via termial ?

Comment: @jayeshkv Thank you so much. I used the dotnet restore and it solved the issue.